# Using PHP functions that work by reference on calltime request

Tags: php, performance, function, reference, pass-by-reference

We know it's not possible to request a function (any function) to work by reference at call time. A function is either/or, depending on whether its arguments are defined with `&$reference` or not.

However... there are times when I'd love to call a function by reference; and times when I need that return value. So. I'm thinking of implementing a pattern like this into a bunch of my helper functions:

```
function might_ref_it(&$what_src, $return=AS_REF) 
{
    $what = $what_src;
    $what = 'b' . $what . 'a';
    // or $what[] = 123456;

    if ($return == AS_REF) {
        $what_src = $what;
    } else {
        return $what;
    }
}
```

I've benchmarked this on a good couple of cases with: 1. function that returns a value, 2. function that works by reference, 3. per above, both with and without requested reference. Performance in each case is virtually identical. I was expecting to see memory differences when I piped in larger data; yet noticed nothing worth mentioning. Suppose PHP (on 7.0.2) optimizes well here.

So then... **the question**. Do you see any drawbacks to this approach? I'm not immediately catching any; since performance seems to be (surprisingly) identical, and I don't mind the little bits of extra code that go into a function with this. But I may be missing something dreadful. What say?

---

*A note on the last test I did.* Wanted to see some clear memory impact, since there ought to be some with the duplicated variable. So I tossed in the output of `str_repeat(md5(mt_rand(1000, 9999)), 100000)` 10 times into the loops; being 3.05 MB of stringy bulk per seed. And then an array with a shuffled `range(0,99999)`; being 1.70 MB worth of arrayed integer noise per seed.

Using a vanilla `reference` function munched up 46 MB; and using a `returns value` function took 86 MB. Using the above "dual function" with "returns value" also took 86 MB. But calling the dual worker by reference surprisingly took the same 46 MB; no penalty on the `$what = $what_src;` duplication. (N.B. Memory usage is the same, how-so-ever many times I loop over the 10 seeds. Arrays took more memory; 68 MB and 122 MB; with the same usage pattern as above.)

I could probably tune my bench setup a bit more to fish out further variance. But nothing's immediately jumping out at me and screaming that this is performance-wise a bad idea...

---

**Updates:** One downside to this approach I've just encountered. You can't pass an objects' return values etc. by reference; `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference`. If I want to use such a function on the value returned by an object call, I have to first assign it into a vanilla variable. Regardless of whether the object's data is passed in with an  `AS_REF` return flag or not. Hmm...

Comment: @AbraCadaver If you decide to vote to close, do it because it's off-topic here. On-topicness on other SE sites is irrelevant.

Comment: Just a thing to bear in mind. PHP optimizes memory usage by not making actual copies of data until you perform a modification to it -- that should then only affect one of both copies. Some PHP implementations will only at *that time* pull the shared storage apart.

Comment: @AbraCadaver See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users). This question would not be on-topic at Code Review because it is hypothetical code.

Comment: As I understand, SO welcomes questions on specific code problems and also on software algorithms, which I understand to include stuff like this. It's a practical programming question with a sample of functional code included; asking whether this is a sound way of solving "how do I optionally pass a reference at call-time", or if it's gonna bite me in the buttocks. Why would it be off-topic here.

Comment: @trincot yes indeed, and that's why I'm a bit puzzled that there's no difference in memory usage when I do the `$what = $what_src; $what = 'b' . $what . 'a';` bit -- which is where the two diverge. The difference only shows when I choose to return a value instead of tossing it back to the referenced variable.

Comment: I would be interested to see what would happen if you did something more intrusive like `$what = $what_src; $what = shuffle($what);` where of course your *what_src* has to be an array.